# Google Charts how to fix hyphen converted to &#8211;

Tags: google-visualization

In my data array I have

```
'Member - joined 2008'
```

however when I load my chart tooltip shows <kbd>&#8211;</kbd> instead:

[image]

How do I fix it to get a hyphen instead of an HTML entity spelled out for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is unrelated to the Google Charts.

It's being caused by the php I'm using, specifically Elegant Theme's Divi.

Answer (score 1):

seems to work fine here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', {role: 'tooltip', type: 'string'}],
    ['2013',  1000, 'Member - joined 2005'],
    ['2014',  1170, 'Member - joined 2006'],
    ['2015',  660,  'Member - joined 2007'],
    ['2016',  1030, 'Member - joined 2008']
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: is there more you can share? how are you loading the tooltip?

Comment: Apparently it's an issue caused by something else on my website... when I isolate source code of the chart - it works fine, just as yours does. Very weird, but thank you for help.